# jersey - How to use a Resource Method with multiple @FormParam of custom type

Tags: jersey

I use jersey and have a method in my Resource class which has multiple parameters. These parameters are filled using `@FormParam` but the problem is, the type of the parameters are custom java types, not some primitives or `String`. I want to convert the value of parameters from `json` to custom java types. If I use `@Cosume(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`, then I cannot use multiple parameters and if I remove it, parameters cannot be converted from json to their java instances.

```java
@POST @Path("/add")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String add(@FormParam("source") BookEntity source, @FormParam("author") AuthorEntity a) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException, TransformationException
{
        ...
}
```

If I change the parameter types to `String` and then use Jackson deserialization, I can deserialize json parameters to java instances but I want to do it for other methods too and get it done automatically.

I tried to use the approach used in [Custom Java type for consuming request parameters](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1399) but I cannot make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom type mapper.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423340/produces-provider-media-type-matching/16764824#16764824)

Anyway by default Jersey tries to map received json object representation using JAXB. Obiously you must annotate your objects.