# Jersey failed with request header application/xml

Tags: xml, rest, jersey

I'm new to jersey. I've a test rest for return a Map.

```
    @GET
    @Path("/maptest")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Map<String, TestObject> mapTest()
            throws JdException {
        // return a non-empty HashMap contains String-TestObject
    }

}
```

It works fine if request head is set to */* or application/json. But failed with exception if request head is application/xml:

```
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.HashMap, and Java type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, TestObject>, and MIME media type application/xml was not found
    ... 31 more
```

I've added XmlRootElement annotation to TestObject. It works with application/xml if return type is set to `List<TestObject>`. Can't XML handle Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey DOES NOT provide a MessageBodyWriter for Maps, so you cannot return a Map; on the contrary, Jersey DOES provide a MessageBodyWriter for Collections, and that's why it works for Collections

Fortunately you have some options:

1. Write a custom MessageBodyWriter (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423340/produces-provider-media-type-matching/16764824#16764824))
2. Return a custom object wrapping your map and make it xml-serializable by jaxb; you'll have to write a XmlMapAdapter (see [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jaxb-and-javautilmap) or [this](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html))