# Sending back a list of files on a REST post

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am developing a REST-Webservice with Jersey 1.17. I have two server where are running on two Tomcats-AppServer. The First Tomcat sending some data two the second. This takes this data and extract some files on his system. Now is my question is it possible to send several files back to the First Tomcat  Server. With one file I bring it to work:

**Tomcat 1**

```
Client client = Client.create();

WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/...");

ObjectMapper objektMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String input = null;
try {
  input = objektMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonMappingWebservice);//some JSON-Values
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {      
  e.printStackTrace();
}

ClientResponse response = webResource
  .type("application/json")
  .post(ClientResponse.class, input);

// this is what I want to 
List<File> file = (List<File>) response.getEntity(File.class);have

String sCurrentLine;
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.get(1).getAbsolutePath()));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
}
```

**Tomcat 2**

```
@POST
@Path("/generate")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response erstelleBericht(JsonMappingWebservice jsonMappingWebservice) {
  List<String> dateiPfade = Steuerung.erstelleExportDateien(jsonMappingWebservice);
  List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

  for (String pfad : dateiPfade) {
    files.add(new File(pfad));
  }

  return Response.ok(files, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build();
}
```

**Error**

```
A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type class java.util.ArrayList, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found
```

Comment: Perhaps try to transfer *one* `File` first. See https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e3510

Comment: Thanks for your tip, I have this try and it works, but I need a list of files

Comment: How do you thing the files should be separated in the response? `application/octet-stream` means "one big file".

Comment: Oh, this is not what I want. What is an alternative a application/zip

Comment: @LutzHorn is there one possibiltiy to achieve my goal, I am a newcomer in Jersey developing

Answer (score 0):

The error stands for the inhabillity of jersey to serialize a List over the wire. In fact your resource method **produces** an octect stream representing a **list** of files, so you'll need a custom **MessageBodyWriter** to transform your list of files to an octect stream and a custom **MessageBodyReader** to transform back the octect stream into a list of files

In order to represent a list of files in a binary format I think you could convert each file into BASE64 and then put them all along a stream, separating each file BASE64 representation from the next with some kind of boundary

Something like:

> [File BASE 64]
>
> --boundary--
>
> [File BASE 64]
>
> -- boundary--
>
> [File BASE 64]

With this List to binary format transformer your'd have to create a **MessageBodyWriter** that will send the data over the wire

In the receiver side, you'll have to do the reverse operation, to get a List from the binary data. You'd put this logic into a **MessageBodyReader**

In order to build the **MessabeBodyWriter** and **MessageBodyReader** look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423340/produces-provider-media-type-matching/16764824#16764824)